# Como faço para pegar um argumento no Web2Py

Tags: python, web2py

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou produzindo uma aplicação em W2P, com um CRUD, na parte de apagar um item estou querendo pegar o id através de um form e desse id remover o item o DB.

Estou tentando através deste código

def apagar():

```
form = FORM('Informe o ID do item que deseja remover', INPUT(_name='id'),   INPUT(_type='submit'))

db(lista.id==request.args(0, cast=int)).delete()

return dict(form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o [SQLFORM.factory](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-factory) para fazer isso, segue exemplo:

```
def apagar():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('id_deletar', label='Informe id...'))
    if form.process().accepted:
        id_deletar = form.vars.id_deletar
        db(db.lista.id==id_deletar).delete()
    return dict(form=form)
```

Outra opção, utilizando os argumentos da URI, seria:

```
def apagar():
    id_deletar = request.args(0)
    if id_deletar:
        db(db.lista.id==id_deletar).delete()
        form = False
    else:
        form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('id_deletar', label='Informe id...'))
        if form.process().accepted:
            id_deletar = form.vars.id_deletar
            redirect('apagar', args=id_deletar)
    return dict(form=form)
```

Porém, a primeira opção é realmente a mais ideal. Já que é uma boa prática não fazer alterações em requisições GET(segundo exemplo), e sim através de POST(primeiro exemplo).